# Cannot get CSS to apply to HTML file

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=“UTF-8” />
    <title>Footer Design</title>
    <link rel=“stylesheet” type=“text/css” href=“style.css” />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id=“footer”>
      <div id=“footer-col-one”>
        <h3>Categories</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Snow</li>
          <li>Surf</li>
          <li>Travel</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id=“footer-col-two”>
        <h3>Navigation</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>About</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id=“footer-col-three”>
        <h3>Follow Me</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Facebook</li>
          <li>Twitter</li>
          <li>Instagram</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For some reason I cannot get my CSS stylesheet to apply. It's not the same directory as this html file. I'm using TextEdit and set it up for use with html & css. I did notice that any where I had double quotes I'm getting some weird output on Chrome Developer Tools like the following:

```
<link rel=â€œstylesheetâ€ type=â€œtext/cssâ€ href=â€œstyle.cssâ€ />
```

Comment: Oops the code is showing up in chrome developer tools like this:
<link rel=â€œstylesheetâ€ type=â€œtext/cssâ€ href=â€œstyle.cssâ€ />

Comment: Bad copy / paste ? Replace all your double quotes.

Comment: Please provide a list of your directory structure.

Comment: Use real quotes, not left/right quotes.

Comment: hi! welcome to Stack Overflow! what @Brad mentioned is that the character you have is `“` for left quotes and `”` for right quotes. In general, in most programming-like settings you'll want to use `"`. The other symbols (`“`, `”`) often cause issues. Try it out and let us know!

Comment: The issue is explained below. But you also said the CSS stylesheet is not in the same directory as the HTML file, and the link says it is. Is that OK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't delimit HTML attribute values with `“` characters, you must use `"` or `'`.

[image: zoomed in screenshot of the above text]

Left/Right quotes will be treated as part of the value (and thus the URL) and not as HTML special characters.

Your problem is most likely caused by writing code using a Word Processor with Smart Quotes turned on. Use a text editor (I'm fond of Sublime Edit 2 myself, but there are many other excellent choices such as Komodo Edit and Brackets).

This would have been picked up (albeit not explicitly) had you [used a validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: I didn't even see this the first time looking at his code. Good spot.

Comment: Alternatively, the quotation marks can be simply omitted, except in some special cases. In the example, no quotation marks are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this source formatting .Do not use “ . Use " . If your style.css file is in the other location means suppose that style.css is in the css folder so give the path like href="css/style.css"

Hope the answer and use this below html code which I have modified!

Footer Design

```
<body>
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footer-col-one">
    <h3>Categories</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Snow</li>
      <li>Surf</li>
      <li>Travel</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-col-two">
    <h3>Navigation</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-col-three">
    <h3>Follow Me</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Facebook</li>
      <li>Twitter</li>
      <li>Instagram</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```